# Kineticjs Image Cache not working in ver 5.1

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I recently tried to upgrade to kineticjs 5.1.0 from 5.0.1
after the upgrade the cache function doesn't seem to work for images.

I have made a fiddle that reproduces the code using the [animals on beach game tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-animals-on-the-beach-game-with-kineticjs/).

here is the fiddle with 5.1.0 [animals on beach tutorial with 5.1.0](http://jsfiddle.net/lhenning/vvduX/)

```
animal.cache();
animal.drawHitFromCache();
animal.filters([
          Kinetic.Filters.Blur,
          Kinetic.Filters.Brighten
        ]);
```

here is the fiddle with 5.0.1 [animals on beach tutorial with 5.0.1](http://jsfiddle.net/lhenning/XKZ39/)

```
animal.cache();
animal.drawHitFromCache();
animal.filters([
          Kinetic.Filters.Blur,
          Kinetic.Filters.Brighten
        ]);
```

What do I need to change to get this tutorial to work with 5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fiddles will not work, because of cross-domain limitations.
Look at this demo: http://jsbin.com/wicav/2/edit. Works fine with v5.1.0

```
image.cache();
image.drawHitFromCache();
image.filters([
          Kinetic.Filters.Blur,
          Kinetic.Filters.Brighten
]);
image.blurRadius(10);
```

**update:** (for v5.1.0) You have to apply filters AFTER you added shape to layer, until such problem will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me see if I understand. What you have done is put the image actually inside the javascript so that it doesn't think there is any cross domain issues. How do you use an image that is not in the js? and How are the cross-domain limitations different in v5.0.1 from v5.1.0?

Comment: (In my fiddles 5.0.1 displays the images. v5.1.0 displays nothing.)

Comment: You have to use image in same domain. There are no any cross-domain limitation between version.

Comment: Maybe I am looking in the wrong spot. If the problem is the cross domain limitations then why don't my two fiddles produce the same results? Teh only difference between the two is that one is 5.0.1 and the other is 5.1.0

Comment: I think I am found. You don't see anything on v5.1.0 demo, right? Thats because on same case you can not apply cache BAFORE adding shape to layer. Edited version: http://jsfiddle.net/SkY9p/ Exactly same results as for v5.0.1

Comment: I see so now you have to add the shape to a layer before calling cache. That sounds like the problem I am seeing I'll try it out.

Comment: That was the problem. Could you update the answer so I can mark it as correct.  Thanks

Comment: Updated. I will look at this problem soon.